# Angular app should stay logged in, until app is open in browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one Angular app with authentication, everything is working good as expected.

But we need that application/session/token should be valid even though there is not activity and app is still open in browser.

and token should be expired only if user do logout himself.

I have an idea, but don't know how should I implement it at application level.

I want to sent one request to API that will refresh the accesstoken every 10 mins.

Where can I implement this logic.

Thanks in advanced.
Danyal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well on the front end you can keep the token saved in a cookie or $window.sessionStorage and you can keep using it for the further API calls which need authentication. You can create a factory to save token

```
 .factory('Authentication', function ($window){

    return {

     store_token: function(token){
        $window.sessionStorage.setItem('token', token);
     },


     get_token: function(){
       return $window.sessionStorage.getItem("token");
     }
  };
 });
```

Then in controller

```
  .controller( 'MyCtrl', function ( $scope, Athentication, Api, $interval){

  function myfunction()
     Api.get_token({username: $scope.username, password: $scope.password}).$promise.then(function(data){
       if(data.success){
         Authentication.store_token(data.token);

       }
     });
  myfunction(); 
  $interval(myfunction, 1000 * 60 * 10); 
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.

Yes, that is what we are doing, but token is also stored in Redis cache in backend for 10 mins, and this token can't be refresh unless some requests are made.

thats mean, no activity happens on page then that token expires. and I want to send one token validate request while user is idle, to keep token alive.

Comment: That's mean I have to activate that interval in every controller, right? and there is not way for defining that call globally after user is logged in.

Comment: use interval in app.run